# Does acceleration come from a change in current?

Tags: current, ac, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

I have a current connected to a wire and let's say when we measure the current at a particular time it reads differently than it does after some time.

Does this imply the current is AC?

I'm asking this because I observed this in an experiment. My experiment consisted of a current passing through a wire and producing a magnetic field and therefore producing a force to move an object by x meters. The current, while the object was in motion, was different at two points. Does this imply the current is AC? It does make sense that current changes at different times since force by an electromagnetic force can be described as *F = BIL* and force arises from acceleration. Does this acceleration come from the change in current?

Comment: Diagram up your experiment. Details matter in understanding what you really need to get at. (This was evident during the Einstein-Bohr debates!) Deducing theory into an experiment requires a thorough description of the experimental setup. You don't get to isolate/reduce the question unless you know enough about the topic to know what you remove is okay. (Which means you already know the answers. A mass forced x meters with same starting and ending momentum means lost energy somewhere, for example.) Write more, please, about your setup and observations.

Answer (score 0):

A change in current level (magnitude) is just a \$\Delta\$.  Going from 1Amp to 2Amps and back to 1Amp is just a change in level, or pulsating.

Alternating Current (AC) changes directions, back and forth.

[image]

[Image source wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current)

Comment: AC absolutely doesn't need to change direction (sign). AC is *any* periodically variable current, irrespective of its average value. The mean voltage doesn't need to be zero!

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica but in AC the electrons don't migrate as the electric field reverses its direction periodically. In pulsating DC, the electrons migrate because the electric field is always in one direction. Doesn't this change anything? I think this is similar to deceleration and negative acceleration...

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I hear what you are saying, but I'm not sure when an AC wave is superimposed with DC, creating an offset such that it doesn't cross zero anymore, that it can still truly be classified as AC.  It's not alternating anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration can take place without a change in current or voltage. If there is no friction or other force opposing the movement of an object, a constant force will result in acceleration. However most systems will have friction and aerodynamic drag. The force due to friction will remain relatively constant as the speed of the object increases, but aerodynamic drag will increase in proportion to speed squared.

You also need to be aware of losses due to resistance and other factors in the electromagnetic system. There may also be electromagnetic energy stored or released.

Conservation of energy is the important thing to remember in analyzing the overall combined electromagnetic and mechanical system.